# Find can we find the supplementary of a complex subspace of complex dimension one (real dim 2)?

Tags: linear-algebra

we identify $\mathbb{C^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^6}$, ie $(z_1,z_2,z_3)=(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3).$ Where $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{R}.$

Let H defined by:

$H=\lbrace(z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb{C^3}/~~z_1+z_2=0, z_3=0\rbrace$

H is a complex subspace of complex dim one (i.e. real dim 2). As we can see 
$H=\operatorname{Span}_\mathbb{R}\lbrace (1,1,-1,-1,0,0);(1,0,-1,0,0,0)$

Question: what is the supplementary H' of H in $\mathbb{R^6}?$ This supplementary will be of dimension four.

can any one help me to find Span of H'?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! A supplementary  subspace is not unique, unless it is $0$.

Comment: Yes. i just want to get one or two exampls. i cannot determine four vectors of H'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a *supplementary* subspace? I assume you refer what is called sous-espace supplémentaire in French. We can choose to compute just the orthogonal complement w.r.t. the standard scalar product. So You want to find a basis of the real space

$$H^\perp=\{x\in\mathbf R^6\mid \langle v, x\rangle=\langle w, x\rangle=0\},$$

where $v, w$ are the two (real) basis vectors of $H$. These are two homogeneoues linear equations:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1&-1&0&0\\1&0&-1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}x=0.$$

Solving this system using Gaußian elimination yields the reduced row echelon form

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
and thus

$$H^\perp=\operatorname{span}\bigl[(0,0,0,0,0,1), (0,0,0,0,1,0), (0,1,0,1,0,0), (1,0,1,0,0,0)\bigr].$$

You get any other supplementary space from that one by adding abritrary vectors from $H$ to these basis vectors of $H^\perp$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is what I want. Now if you could of course: can we choose an other supplementary H' of H witch satify the condition: $span (H_i,H_ j, H')= \mathbb{R^6}, i\neq j \in {1.2.3.4 }$ . where
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
&H_1=&Span_\mathbb{R}\big[(1,0,0,0,0,0);(0,1,0,0,0,0)\big],\\
&H_2=&Span_\mathbb{R}\big[(0,0,1,0,0,0);(0,0,0,1,0,0)\big],\\
&H_3=& Span_\mathbb{R}\big[(0,0,0,0,1,0);(0,0,0,0,0,1)\big],\\
&H_4=&Span_\mathbb{R}\big[(1,0,1,0,1,0);(0,1,0,1,0,1)\big].\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @jojo I think I do not understand your comment. If there is something left unclear with my answer, feel free to rephrase your comment. If the answer answers your question, please be so kind to mark it as an answer and/or vote for it.

Comment: yes in fact your answer is correct and answer my question. I just ask your help for a second question related to the first: the question is alredy mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: @Jojo I don't understand your last comment, so rephrase the question therein, please.